# Printing Comments in Python with integers

Tags: python, pretty-print

```
def triangular(n):
    tri = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        tri = tri + i

    print ("The answer is equal to" +(tri))

triangular(4)
```

I just need help with the print statement because it doesn't work. I am trying to print the answer is equal to tri

Answer (score 7):

```
print("The answer is equal to", tri)
```

or

```
print("The answer is equal to %i"%tri)
```

or

```
print("The answer is equal to {}".format(tri))
```

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) also have some more ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast your `int` to a `str`.

```
# str is optional here because print will call str on its arguments for you
print("The answer is equal to", str(i))
```

or

```
# str is not optional here because you are concatenating
print("The answer is equal to " + str(i))
```